# dsn for ms access 2003 in windows 7

Tags: ms-access, windows-7, dsn

I am trying to create a dsn for ms access in windows 7. But its showing:

"The setup routines for the Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb) ODBC driver could not be found.Please reinstall the driver. " and 
"Error found:
The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application."

I am using Microsoft Office 2003 version. I have tried to run C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe also. But still getting this error. Now can anyone please suggest me to solve this error..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the setup again for Office 2003 and make sure to install the appropriate ODBC drivers:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/no-odbc-drivers-available-for-excel-or-access-in/001c234b-dfd5-4378-a325-c4f1482fb6fd

If you open ODBC, you should be able to the full list of drivers installed and verify that either the older ones from Office 2003, or the newer ones you installed, are available.  If they are, you can create a new ODBC DSN or edit the existing one to point to the drivers you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have rerun the setup of office 2003.Its working if I go through C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe